# Excel - calculate date time

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-2007

I am trying to calculate the hour difference between two times. What I've been doing now only gives me hour indications like `1:30, 2:45, etc` but I can't make diagrams based on these values. If I get `2:30` as the hour difference, it should become `2,5`. if the difference is `2:45` that should be `2,75`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to subtract 1 datetime from the other.  Try this:

1. In cell A1, enter **"09/17/2012 10:00"** (Excel should automatically recognize this as a date)
2. In cell A2, enter **"09/17/2012 11:30"**
3. In cell A3, **"=(A2-A1)*24"**.  The result is 1.5.

The problem may be that you are trying to subtract 1 'time' from another 'time' without a date component.  In that case, Excel may not recognize your value as a 'time'.  Try adding a dummy date to the beginning of the time.

One limitation of this is that you will get an error response of "########" if the 2nd date is earlier than the 1st (because the result is negative).  If this is an issue, try **"=ABS(A2-A1)*24"** instead.

Comment: Another issue is that Excel automatically formats the cell with the formula/result as a date, assuming the first two cells really are dates (or at least one is formatted as a date and the other is a number that represents a valid date).

Comment: Kudos to @DougGlancy for suggesting the *24 part.

Answer (score 3):

Change your formula to:

```
(B2-A1)*24
```

and format as General

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, I just get ########### (even editing the cell size).

Comment: how about with the parentheses I just added?

Comment: And you are sure the two cells have actual dates in them, and that the subtraction, without my answer, resolves to an actual date?  I assumed yes, because in your question the subtraction works.  I ask because the "#######" indicates a negative date.

Comment: Yes, or what would you suggest?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16792/discussion-between-doug-glancy-and-tom)

Comment: Sorry Doug, I didn't catch your response for chat discussion. I hope you appreciate the up vote :)